# error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct XXX’ from type ‘char **’

Tags: c

I get an error in my C code:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct command’ from type ‘char **’.
```

I don't know why can't I assign char *var[] to char **.

```
typedef struct Appstruct{
    char *app[10];
} APP;
struct command
{
   char **argv;
};
struct command cmd[10];
for(i=0;i<pipecount+1;i++)
{
       cmd[i]=APPS[i].app;
}
```

But if I assign directly one by one to the array (without use loop to assign) it's ok like that:

```
struct command cmd [] = { APPS[0].app, APPS[1].app };
```

How should I modify my code?

Comment: This `struct command cmd [] = { APPS[0].app, APPS[1].app }; ` is not correct as well. Raise the compilers warning level to be notified about the issue. It should be `struct command cmd [] = {{ APPS[0].app }, { APPS[1].app }};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
struct command cmd [] = { APPS[0].app, APPS[1].app };
```

in fact is the sloppy version of the correct

```
struct command cmd [] = {
 {APPS[0].app}, 
 {APPS[1].app}
};
```

which initialises the array of `struct command` `cmd` with two `struct`s, which each in turn are initialised using `APPS[0].app` and `APPS[1].app`.

So to mimic the initialisation's behaviour as an assignment do the following:

```
  for(i=0;i<pipecount+1;i++)
  {
    cmd[i]=(struct command){APPS[i].app};
  }
```

Comment: oh I got it, thank u so much! your explanation is so clear!

Answer (score 4):

You can’t assign to the `struct` object, you need to assign to its member:

```
cmd[i].argv = APPS[i].app;
```

Comment: "*You can’t assign to the struct object*" well, no, you can, just not as the way the OP does.

Comment: @alk Fair enough but I’d posit that it’s not what the OP *wants* to do. That said, +1 on your answer.